# Writing cellfun output using Matlab code for a folded data set

Tags: matlab

I have data a data file like this:

```
0 -7.09381e-10 7.88112e-09
1 -3.365e-09 3.96397e-08
2 -1.74014e-09 1.3715e-08
3 -6.79327e-10 4.74787e-09
4 -1.92799e-10 1.56609e-09
5 6.53422e-11 5.09169e-10
6 5.21863e-11 1.73983e-10
7 5.64361e-11 6.29614e-11
0 -9.44027e-10 8.14559e-09
1 -2.02866e-09 4.29019e-08
2 -2.2109e-10 1.57419e-08
3 4.55366e-11 5.97503e-09
4 1.70868e-10 2.28134e-09
5 1.90134e-10 8.52557e-10
6 4.4223e-11 3.2142e-10
7 7.2096e-12 1.22047e-10
```

and another 100 sets of data in this sequence one after another. The first column indices are time index. I fold the data and then calculate the ratio of column 2 and 3 using the following matlab code:

```
data_jknife =dlmread('datafile.txt',' ');
metadata = data_jknife(:,1); % a bidimensional array data_jknife, and want to access all its elements on the first column
data1 = data_jknife(:,2);%accessing all the elements on the second clomun
data2 = data_jknife(:,3);
groupedMetaData = arrayfun(@(x) metadata(x:4:end), 1:4 ,'UniformOutput',false );

groupedData1 = arrayfun(@(x) data1(x:4:end), 1:4 ,'UniformOutput',false ); %grouping data from the second column
groupedData2 = arrayfun(@(x) data2(x:4:end), 1:4 ,'UniformOutput',false );

flippedData1 = fliplr(groupedData1);
flippedData1 = flippedData1(1:2);
foldedData1 = cellfun(@(x,y)  mean([x y],2), flippedData1 ,groupedData1(1:numel(flippedData1)),'UniformOutput',false);
flippedData2 = fliplr(groupedData2);
flippedData2 = flippedData2(1:4);
foldedData2 = cellfun(@(x,y)  mean([x y],2), flippedData2 ,groupedData2(1:numel(flippedData2)),'UniformOutput',false);

foldedData = cellfun(@rdivide, foldedData1, foldedData2,'UniformOutput',false);
```

So the output of the   foldedData   should be like this:

```
0 R(0)
1 R(1)
0 R'(0)
1 R'(1)
2 R'(2)
```

where R is 2nd column divided by 3rd column of the folded data for corresponding time slices. Now I would like to write the output in a file in the above format. But I don't know how to do that. Could anybody please help me with that? Thanks in advance. So here is the numerical values of the operation
ok. So the folding acts like this for the first sequence of the data set:
2nd column elements(I take average of t= 0,3,4,7 data)

```
((-7.09381*10^-10) + (-6.79327*10^-10) + (-1.92799*10^-10) +  (5.64361*10^-11))/4 = 


-3.81268*10^-10
```

3rd column elements:

```
((7.88112*10^-09) + (4.74787*10^-09) + (1.56609*10^-09) + (6.29614*10^-11))/4 = 
3.56451*10^-9
```

then I take average of t= 1,2,5,7 data. So the 2nd column is:

```
((-3.365*10^-09) + (-1.74014*10^-09) + (6.53422*10^-11) + (5.64361*10^-11))/4=
-1.24584*10^-9
```

3rd column is :

```
((3.96397*10^-08) + (1.3715*10^-08) + (5.09169*10^-10) + (1.73983*10^-10))/4=
1.35095*10^-8
```

So for the first sequence of data the output is :

```
R0 = (-3.81267725`*^-10)/(3.5645103500000007`*^-9) = -0.106962
R1 = (-1.245840425`*^-9)/(1.35095*10^-8) = -0.0922198
```

therefore the desired output for the 1st sequence is :

```
0 -0.106962
1 -0.0922198
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
%%// input_filepath and output_filepath are the paths to the input and
%%// output files

d1 = dlmread(input_filepath,' ')

t1 = permute(reshape(d1',24,[]),[1 3 2]) %%//'
d1 = permute(reshape(t1,3,8,[]),[2 1 3])

d2 = d1([0 3 4 7]+1,[2 3],:)
d22 = d1([1 2 5 7]+1,[2 3],:)

t1 = [mean(d2) ; mean(d22)]
t2 = t1(:,1,:)./t1(:,2,:)

out = [repmat([0:size(t1,1)-1]',size(t2,3),1) t2(:)] %%//'
datacell = cellstr(num2str(out))

fid1 = fopen(output_filepath,'w');
for k = 1:size(datacell,1)
    fprintf(fid1,'%s\n',datacell{k,:});
end
fclose(fid1);
```

Comment: Hi Divakar, this is not quite working for me. And I also just edited a parts of the codes. If I plot them the graph looks correct. As I am folding and taking avg of the data two times so the output is actually like this:0 R(0)
1 R(1)
0 R'(0)
1 R'(1)
2 R'(2)  Because first there were 8 time slices, I fold two times.

Comment: So, for the given values, could you post the actual values instead of `R(0)`, `R(1)`, etc. for `foldedData`? Please edit the question with those?

Comment: Hi Divakar, as the output is too long, I have added it at the end of my post. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @user3389597 Check out the edited code and see if it works with the given 2 sets of data case!

Comment: I was not looking for this actually. Because this is just adding the numbers and divide by hand. I can do this. I was looking for something general...because I am dealing with huge set of data. Thanks.

Comment: @user3389597 Actually I have tested it and it must work for a big datasize too. Did you test it out on your large sets?

Comment: Hi Divakar, The code you have written is to do the operation in the I intend to. This operation is already done by the code I submitted here. You can see the "foldedData=cellfun(@rdivide, foldedData1, foldedData2,'UniformOutput',false);".......and the lines before this. All I asked for is to how do I print "foldedData" in a file.

Comment: @user3389597 The printing must be taken care of by the last 5 lines of my code. Didn't those work? or got some error?